# Structure of the Jacobson radical of the Group Algebra .

Tags: gap, computational-algebra

Is it possible to find the structure description of the Jacobson radical $J(FG)$ of a group algebra FG, where F and G are finite field and group respectively in GAP?

I choose the group algebra $F_3D_{30}$, where $F$ is a finite field of characteristic $3$ and $D_{30}$ is the dihedral group of order $30.$ Actually I need the algebraic structure of $1+J(F_3D_{30})$ as it is a subgroup of the unit group $U(F_3D_{30})$, so I am thinking first the structure of $J(F_3D_{30})$. I tried as

gap> RadicalOfAlgebra(GroupRing(GF(3),D30));

<algebra of dimension 20 over GF(3)>

gap> H:=RadicalOfAlgebra(GroupRing(GF(3),D30));;

gap> Size(H);

3486784401

gap> IsAbelian(H);

false

gap> Center(H);

<algebra of dimension 10 over GF(3)>

brk_3> StructureDescription(H);

Error, no method found!

StructureDescription is not working. Is there any way to find its algebraic structure using GAP? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of structure description are you hoping for? It is an ideal. So the most interesting information is probably a basis of $J$ and a basis of $J/J^2$, which describe the minimal arrow generators of the algebra. I think you can choose generator $x_i$ of the group $1+J$ and then obtain the group $1+J=Group(<x_i>)$ in GAP. Then the command structure description works for (small) groups. Your example might be much too big for a structure description.

Comment: @Mare it’s non abelian group of exponent 3 so I want it’s structure as semi direct product of cyclic groups of order 5.

Comment: cyclic groups of order 3

Comment: @neelkanth is [wedderga](https://gap-packages.github.io/wedderga/) package of any help? See [its documentation here](https://gap-packages.github.io/wedderga/doc/chap0_mj.html)

Comment: @OlexandrKonovalov ok I will try it and tell

Comment: Please do! Also, `StructureDescription` is for finite groups, not for algebras.

Comment: @OlexandrKonovalovis it possible in GAP that it gives structure of Jacobson Radical J(FG) of finite group algebra as a semi direct product of cyclic groups ?